# SAPUI5 logOff() with Shell

Tags: shell, logout, sapui5, logoff

How would I realize the logoff function in Shell control having this API example: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.ApplicationHeader.html#event:logoff

```
    var oLogoff = new sap.ui.commons.ApplicationHeader();

    ... // within the Shell (function logout)
    logout : function(oEvent) {
        oLogoff.fireLogoff(); // this.fireLogoff() also not working
    },
    ...
```

EDIT:
`oShell.fireLogout();` 

--> seems to be right, but this Ends up in an error "Not enough stack Memory" .. anybody any help?

I expect returning to a Login-page ... is this handled automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `logout` function of the Shell control is only an event you can use to trigger your own logout function when someone clicks the logout button in the Shell header (see [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.ux3.Shell.html#event:logout)).

`oShell.fireLogout()` ends up in a stack overflow as you´re calling your own function again and again.

The logout itself is not done for you automatically. Depending on your deployment scenario the logout implementation differs as the session management is done differently.

Answer (score 3):

Use the shells Container logout-method:

```
sap.ushell.Container.logout();
```